# Point of Interest icon stays white after exploring

Tags: mass-effect-andromeda

I've just finished up the majority of exploration in the Kadara badlands. I'm used to certain map icons turning blue to indicate that you've fully explored them/found all the loot (like with Remnant sites). However, I've looked all over the Points of Interest, and found as much loot as I could, but the icons stay white. Is this a glitch, or are they supposed to stay white?

Comment: I've had the same thing and I just started ignoring them, never really figured out why some of them stayed white. Happened on a couple planets for me.

Comment: Some insight [here](https://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/168599-mass-effect-andromeda/75151961).  Players say either you missed something or it may be bugged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience the Remnant Site icons for the Vaults never changed to blue, even after completing them. For other Remnant Sites they seemed to change after opening one or containers at the site.

The exception to this rule for me was on Eos, where two sites never changed to blue. Perhaps there was a bug that was patched after I discovered these sites, which did not correct them.